# Project error when not entering a value

Tags: vb.net, integer

```
If txtAge.Text < 18 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You must be over 18", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    Else : Me.Close()
        Form3.Show()
    End If
```

the code works its just if i choose not to enter any information i want to be notified and brought back my project just crashes and says

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is
>   not valid.'

im not sure where im going wrong maybe converting strings/integers im a beginner so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Int32.TryParse()` :

```
Dim intAge As Int32
If Int32.TryParse(txtAge.Text, intAge) Then
   If intAge < 18 Then
      MessageBox.Show("You must be over 18", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
   End If
Else
   MessageBox.Show("Age was empty or invalid!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End If
```